# How to go from downloading a file to strings - Android

Tags: android, string, download, textview

I have a text file hosted on the internet and I want it downloaded to the internal storage somewhere so that the information can be used while offline but the file can be overwritten with a new file when the time comes for updating from the text file hosted on the internet.

Then I want this text file to be accessed at onCreate once the file is downloaded and the lines of text to be changed into strings which can be used in a TextView @string/stringname123 etc rather than a string which is defined by the system so the string name can be different each time.

Put simply in a list in order.

- Text File downloaded off internet
- Place text file in internal storage for offline use later overwriting any previous file in same location
- TextFile accessed at onCreate
- Text from text file placed into pre-defined string names already placed into the TextView with the attributes for example: android:text="@string/12312345678"

How would this be done? Any help and information is very appreciated!

Comment: From your second paragraph, you've demonstrated you know very little about Android programming. This comment is not meant to disrespect you in any way. Everyone, including myself, have had to begin somewhere (and anyone who disagrees with my claim is a liar). It's just that I would recommend that you revise your initial goal a little and first follow a couple of very basic tutorials on Android (tutorials that don't even deal with downloading things from the internet for now). For instance, you could google for a programming tutorial for building a very basic calculator in Android.

Comment: The basic fact is that the string xml values in Android are packaged and initialized at compile time. And for you to change what's written in a TextView, you would use Java to update -- you wouldn't update them through the string resources in xml.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I do know how to download files from the internet and have got it working but only in external storage and not internal. From there I could probably use a FileInputStream to make it usable in a TextView but I am unsure how. I was writing very fast and reading it back a lot of it does make me sound like I know absolutely nothing. I am new to this but not so new and what I wrote quickly was bad. Sorry, I completely forgot that you cannot change string values at onCreate because they are "hardcoded" as such.

Comment: The mistake you made by writing things down too quickly isn't what's important. The important part is that you went too quickly and you're still going too quickly now. Anyone can just cut and paste code from tutorials and stackoverflow, and assuming the Eclipse gods are with you, make some of that code work on your own Android emulator/devices. As Java Android developers, we're very lucky to be able to find open source examples of code and tutorials for almost anything we want to make. The difficulty then becomes integrating those bits of code from various different places.

Comment: That's why I would recommend you to slow down a little and downgrade your initial goals slightly. Doing it your way isn't going to make you a better developer more quickly. If nothing else, the emotional pay off, of getting something cut and pasted from somewhere else, working and running very quickly, without really making the effort to understand what's going on, may give you a false sense of achievement and may demotivate the hell out of you at the most crucial time when you're trying to complete the last 20% of your project (that wasn't taken care by the cut and pasted code you found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the basic structure is like this, I don't have my computer here but this might help you anyway:

```
 onCreate(){
   if (check whether you have a data connection with [ConnectionManager][1])
      DownloadFile using [AsyncTask][2]
      declare task
      task.execute()
   else
      open file for reading using [InputStream][3]
      parseStringsFromFile()
  }



 public class someTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        string = Downlaodfilefunction using [httpget][4]
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        parseStringsFromFile(result)
    }

 }
```

Sorry I can't be more specific but I'm sure you'll be able to make it work like this.
Ups links don't show up, here they are:

[ConnectionManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

[httpget](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html)